# addition vs comparison

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, micro-optimization

Let say I have an array of 1,000,000 elements with about 90% of 0s and 10% of 1s.

In order to count of 1s, I can do

```
sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    sum+=x[i]
}
```

But I thought maybe comparison is cheaper than addition so this would be better.

```
sum=0;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++) {
    if(x[i]==1)
        sum++;
}
```

But I am not sure. Which one is faster?

Comment: Have you tried profiling your code?

Comment: Even without profiling, I can almost guarantee that the first option is faster unless `sum` happens to be `volatile` or something stupid like that. The second case could also suffer from [branch prediction](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/922184).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to say which one is going to be faster without trying it, but a even a slightly slower instruction without a branch will usually be faster due to [pipelining and branch prediction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/335858).

In your case, the branch predictor will be wrong 90% of the time, reducing the speed quite a bit.

Comment: `wrong 90% of the time` That's not how predictors work.

Comment: I agree with @scientiaesthete here; the branch predictor should get it right 90% of the time. Otherwise it's a lousy predictor. However, the more interesting point is that comparing a number to 1 is essentially the same as adding the number to something. So compare and optionally increment is more work than unconditionally add.